# How can I find and install pacman-color or cope?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, text

I'm using Arch-Linux and I'm trying to install something that colors the text in the terminal (xterm), but not necessarily just for xterm. It would be nice to find something for text without initializing the X server.

I've found (after a little search on google) that `pacman-color` already exists in the AUR, but I haven't managed to extract & install it.

Is there someone that can help me with this problem? I'd like to know the steps for installing `pacman-color`? If you have other suggestions on how I can change the text color, I would be very happy if you could share the answer!

Comment: Hm, how can you use xterm at all without the X server? In `.Xresources`, the most basic color configuration looks something like `xterm*background: black`, `xterm*foreground: green4`, etc. (Maybe I didn't understand you?)

Comment: @Emanuel, yes i know you can't use xterm without initializing X server :) I was also asking if there is a way to color the text in case I don't want to initialize the graphical server. I was changing the text for xterm using the command: `xterm -fg yellow -bg black &`, that i've added to a script that starts what i need from the system. And, like you mentioned, it can also be changed by modifying the `.Xresources` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pacman-color](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=11827) only colours the output for pacman commands.

To colourize a wide range of terminal output for a variety of programmes, you can use a tool like [cope](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=32514).

Both packages are in the [AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR). The Arch Wiki has a good explanation of how to [install AUR packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR#Installing_packages). Essentially, once you have downloaded the tarball (for example, for `pacman-color`), you run `makepkg` and then install the built package with `pacman -U pacman-colour.pkg.tar.xz`.

Comment: So, i've instaled pacman-color and it's ok... but you suggested 'cope' and this sounded better than pacman-color so i've tried to install it and after a lot of dependencies that i had to install separately i've managed to install it but i'm stuck with configuring the path, i simply can't make it work... could you be kind to tell me if you have any ideea what i could do?

Comment: Follow the advice in the [README](https://github.com/trapd00r/cope) and add the path to your shell file (eg., `bashrc`). It should look something like: `PATH=/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/share/dist/Cope:$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

To setup `yaourt`, first add an unofficial repository archlinuxfr to your `/etc/pacman.conf`,

```
[archlinuxfr]
Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch
```

Now do a `pacman -Syu yaourt` to install yaourt, when finished, (You may choose to comment these two lines out when yaourt is installed)

Use `yaourt -S pacman-color` to setup pacman-color, during installation steps, you will be prompt for modifying PKGBUILD and pacman-color.install files, just say `N`, and `Continue to build` it, finally you'll got something like this,

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to install the package.

[image]

Comment: The OP would have to install `yaourt` from AUR first to do that... :)

Comment: @jasonwryan I always want to know what OP is short for?

Comment: Original poster :)

Comment: jasonwryan is right, installing from AUR was one of my problems too... @warl0ck Thank you for the command,solves part of my problem!

Comment: Adding the `[archlinuxfr]` repo is *not* a good idea. One, it has a history of broken and outdated packages, and two the OP should learn how to use `makepkg` if they are going to run Arch. Also, telling someone not to read the PKGBUILD compounds the bad advice.

Comment: @jasonwryan they're not in abs anyway.. But it seems like, without yaourt, you'll need to download PKGBUILD, patches and other files manually and do `makepkg`, am I wrong?

Comment: Doing it manually is the correct way to understand what it going on and to learn how to use Arch. For `pacman-color`, all of the files are in the tarball--it is very straightforward.